# COBOL Record description entry I cannot decipher

Tags: cobol, cobol85

I am examining this example in Cobol 85 from the NIST TestSuite:

```
007700 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         SQ4014.2
007800                                                                  SQ4014.2
007900 01 VARIABLES.                                                    SQ4014.2
008000                                                                  SQ4014.2
008100     03 VKEY                                                      SQ4014.2
008200     XXXXX086.                                                    SQ4014.2
008300                                                                  SQ4014.2
008400                                                                  SQ4014.2
008500 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              SQ4014.2
008600                                                                  SQ4014.2
```

To me it seems wrong because the the record description entry 03 VKEY should be followed by some keyword, like VALUE. It is instead followed by an identifier (XXXXX086) which I do not know how to interpret.
What does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where you got the sample from, it looks like it was directly taken from newcob.val. If extracted "as expected" the COBOL line is:

```
007700 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         SQ4014.2
007800                                                                  SQ4014.2
007900 01 VARIABLES.                                                    SQ4014.2
008000                                                                  SQ4014.2
008100     03 VKEY                                                      SQ4014.2
008200     PIC X(8).                                                    SQ4014.2
008300                                                                  SQ4014.2
008400                                                                  SQ4014.2
008500 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              SQ4014.2
```

so it is as cschneid said: it is to be preprocessed before it is compiled and otherwise would raise an error.

A side note: the test programs say in the header what they test for, this one says:

```
000400*THE FOLLOWING PROGRAM TESTS THE FLAGGING OF HIGH                 SQ4014.2
000500*SUBSET FEATURES THAT ARE USED IN SEQUENTIAL                      SQ4014.2
```

so it does not expect any errors.

The easiest option to extract it I know of is to get a copy of [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/) and ideally run the configure part, then running `make test` in the "tests/cobol85" subdirectory (or use the perl scripts in there to extract the files manually). You'll end up with one subdirectory for each module of the test suite.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would you happen to know how to extract the file validly then?

Comment: @FedericoTomassetti adjusted the answer to include your additional question.

Answer (score 2):

As written, that is a compile error.  Which may be what is being tested by that particular member of the test suite.

It's also possible it is intended to be modified via a preprocessor.  Note other members of the NIST suite with non-standard characters in column 7.

Not all members of the NIST test suite are valid COBOL.

Comment: That was my impression too, but I thought I was probably wrong, not being a Cobol expert